# Black & White SF Movie - Man with Puffy, Black Skin

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have faint memories of a poignant, B&W S.F. movie from the late 50s or early 60s - which may have been British. All I recall is a man dressed in a normal suit, but something had happened to him that made his skin black and puffy, like it was filled with air, and if he touched you, you'd become that way, too. This man was walking around a neighborhood, not trying to hurt people, but maybe trying to return to his home and family. Again, a very faint memory. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Melting_Man?

Comment: [The Hideous Sun Demon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5WFfT5dxYI&feature=youtu.be&t=36m)?

Comment: [The Quatermass Xperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quatermass_Xperiment)?

Comment: Thanks, but not Melting Man, Sun Demon or Quatermass. It was a horror movie, but very intelligent and poignant. I don't believe space travel was involved, but some type of Earthly science project gone wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @bradleydean - Work your way through the checklists here; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Answer (score 4):

This sounds somewhat like "Hand of Death" (1962)

Here is a photo from IMDb.com showing the scientist main character after he is transformed by his experimental formula:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056055/mediaviewer/rm3328131840

Here is the trailer from YouTube. You can see the 'puffy, black' skin at 0:44 of the trailer.